# Mount with kernel NTFS and not NTFS-3G

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, ntfs

I often want to copy files from a Windows machine to linux using an external drive formatted with NTFS. Since this is entirely read-only using NTFS-3G slows down the copy process but the only way I could find to mount with the kernel driver was to purge `ntfs-3g` before mounting...but I feel like there has to be a better way to specify that I want to mount with the kernel driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because `mount.ntfs` is symlinked to `ntfs-3g`, which is what Arch Linux does:

https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/ntfs-3g#n46

You can probably remove the symlink to avoid the need to cycle un/reinstallation of the package. Still, this will probably be reverted when the package is updated (well, ntfs-3g does not get updated very frequently even in rolling release distro like Arch though)

EDIT: Btw there's the `NoExtract=` directive in `pacman.conf`.

Comment: Maybe instead I can rename the ntfs kernel module?

Comment: Not sure. I think that could break things. Also I don't see how it works better than removing the symlink.

Answer (score 4):

You can call `mount` using the `-i` or `--internal-only` flag to force using the kernel driver.

From the `mount` `man` page:

```
  -i, --internal-only
              Don't call the /sbin/mount.filesystem helper even if it exists.
```